# JAVA Why do I get a type error when assigning these variables (T extends Comparable<T>)

Tags: java

So, let's say we have these two classes.

```
public class Main<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   public List<T> toList(T t){
      Node n = new Node();
      n.value = t; //This assignment1 gives no issues.

      List<T> list = new List<T>();
      list.add(n.value); //This assignment2 gives a type error.
      return list;
     }
}

class Node <T extends Comparable<T>> {
   T value = null;
}
```

So, why does assignment1 go through without a type error, while assignment2 gives me the following error:

add (T) in List cannot be applied to (java.lang.Comparable)

It disappears when I do:

```
list.add((T)n.value);
```

But I would like to understand the reason first to figure out if above solution is the correct one.

EDIT: For now, I should specify that the code that uses these classes are Integer objects. So, I as the developer can assume that the T types are the same. But I am not sure if the code has some underlying routine that can change the values during casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node n = new Node();
```

should be

```
Node<T> n = new Node<T>();
```

If you *ever* refer to `Node` without `<something>` after it, you are telling the compiler to ignore *all type checking* on `Node`.  This will give you warnings, as it should.

Comment: It works, thanks! So basically, writing Node<T> will have the compiler check if the T in class declaration Node<T extends Comparable<T>> is the same T as in Main<T extends Comparable<T>>?